# Sentinel usage in Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, sentinel

I have gone through the documentation and cant seem to find much about what I need to do.  I have installed this package [Centaur](https://github.com/SRLabs/Centaur)

From what I understand it is essentially an extension of Sentinel, so should work in the same way.  Once installed and set up, I can create users and roles.  This is all fine.  So in my layout view I provide a link to the clients index page, I want everyone to see this so I dont do any checks.

```
<li class="{{ Request::is('clients*') ? 'active' : '' }}"><a href="{{ route('clients.index') }}">Clients</a></li>
```

Looking at the Users and Roles Controller, I assumed that I needed a constructor in my ClientsController which states the permissions.  This is what I have

```
public function __construct(AuthManager $authManager)
{
    // Middleware
    $this->middleware('sentinel.auth');
    $this->middleware('sentinel.access:users.view', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
    $this->middleware('sentinel.role:administrator');

    // Dependency Injection
    $this->roleRepository = app()->make('sentinel.roles');
    $this->authManager = $authManager;
}
```

What I am attempting to achieve is for users to only view the clients, and admins can update them.  Within my edit roles views I have added the checkboxes

```
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[clients.update]" value="1" {{ $role->hasAccess('clients.update') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        clients.update
    </label>
</div>
<div class="checkbox">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="permissions[clients.view]" value="1" {{ $role->hasAccess('clients.view') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
        clients.view
    </label>
</div>
```

As things stand, the admin can view and update clients.  However, when I log into the system as a normal user, when I click on the link for clients I see

```
 Error: You do not have permission to do that.
```

So when creating new models with Sentinel, what is the process of giving users/roles permissions for certain actions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First [create the role](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#create-a-new-role), then [attach the role to the user](https://cartalyst.com/manual/sentinel/2.0#assign-a-user-to-a-role).

So quick example from links provided:

```
$role = Sentinel::getRoleRepository()->createModel()->create([
    'name' => 'Subscribers',
    'slug' => 'subscribers',
]);

$user = Sentinel::findById(1);

// use this for lookup where you don't already have a role handy
$role = Sentinel::findRoleByName('Subscribers');

$role->users()->attach($user);
```

In your case, probably something like the following role permissions:

```
$role->permissions = [
    "admin.view"   => true,
    "admin.update" => true
    "user.view"    => true,
    "user.update"  => false
];
$role->save();
```

Then checking permissions and type of user in one go...This would be an example of an Admin user trying to update

```
if (Sentinel::inRole('admin') and $user->hasAccess(['admin.update']) {
    //
}
```

I haven't used Sentinel in a long time, you might be able to omit the `inRole` check completely, not sure.

Comment: See, I understand that part.  My problem is this.  I have two roles; admin and user.  I have assigned a user to each role.  This was done when I set things up, within a seed file.  I now have a new Model, Clients.  I need to somehow state that only admins can update Clients, and users can only view them.  What would we the process for this?